# Adding options to multiple 'choice' objects in java

Tags: java, dropdownchoice

The for loop isn't working. I get "Choice cannot be resolved to a variable". I would like to add a group of options to multiple Choice objects added to the generics list. In this example you can see one of these objects (DidWell1) .

```
import java.awt.Choice;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class testing {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    testing window = new testing();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public testing() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final Choice DidWell1 = new Choice();
        DidWell1.setBounds(119, 36, 135, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(DidWell1);

        List<Choice> list = new ArrayList<Choice>();

        list.add(DidWell1);

        String option = "Friday";

        For(Choice choice: list){
            choice.add( option );
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: make a list of days : List<String> days ............... for each day add all element for that array : for(day : days) {  .add(day)  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of Choice objects

```
List<Choice> list = new ArrayList<Choice>();
```

Next add all Didwells to this list.

```
list.add( didwell1 ); etc
```

With this setup adding new options can be done using a For loop:

```
String option = "Friday";

for( Choice choice: list ){
    choice.add( option );
}
```

Or with a While loop:

```
Iterator<Choice> iter = new list.iterator();
while iterator.hasNext(){
    iter.next().add( option );
}
```

Comment: I'm get this error. "Choice cannot be resolved to a variable" at the Foreach line

Comment: if Choice fails again, it should be equal to the classname of your dropdownchoice object.  My guess was that Java.set.Choice was the classname.

Comment: the import is, java.awt.Choice; when I try to type "for( java.awt.Choice choice" it doesn't find it...

Comment: Autocorrect error. I meant awt. Tell me how you declared your Didwells. E.g. Choice didwell1 = new Choice();

Comment: final Choice DidWell8 = new Choice();

Later I want to use the DidWell8.getSelectedItem(). Without final it doesn't work.

Comment: Assuming you are working with java version 5 or  up, the code in my example should work. Check your code for typos.

Comment: well, it says jre7 and ive stripped it down to just that choice bit. (see edited question) still no luck :/

Comment: Update your question with the actual code you have so far.

Comment: my bad. Autocorrect again."For" should be "for", i.e. no capital F. I have updated the answer